# Trouble using ST_DIFFERENCE() function in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, differences

If have this:

```
CREATE TABLE buff as (
  SELECT route_sutton.id, ST_BUFFER(route_sutton.geom, 30) as geom
  FROM route_sutton
)

CREATE TABLE couvert_dif5 AS (
  SELECT nextval('temp_id') AS id, ST_DIFFERENCE(couvert.geom, buff.geom)
  FROM couvert_temp_sutton AS couvert CROSS JOIN buff
)
```

What I want to do is to "take a bite" off of the bigger geometries 'couvert_temp_sutton' using the buffered roads 'route_sutton'.

The resulting relation 'couvert_dif5' returns exactly the same geometries as the original relation 'couvert_temp_sutton'

If I do the operation in QGIS using the Difference tool, everything works and it is fast.

Could someone point me where the problem is?

Comment: What's the CRS of route_sutton.geom? EPSG:4326?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do. Could you add a sketch as a small image into your question? It seems that you are creating buffer areas for "route_sutton", and then you want to cut something out of "couvert_temp_sutton" with the buffered geometries. I do not understand what is the meaning of CROSS JOIN but I guess that you can explain it. Explain as well what kind of table "couvert_temp_sutton" is.

That ST_Difference does work can be tested with plain SQL:

Original geometry A:

```
select ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))');
```

Buffered geometry B:

```
select ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'),1);
```

Difference A-B (smaller minus bigger):

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Difference(ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'),ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'),1)));
Result: GeometryCollection EMPTY
```

Difference B-A (bigger minus smaller):

```
select ST_Difference(ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'),1),ST_GeomFromText('polygon ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 0 0))'));
```

Result as an image:

[image]

I wonder if you'd like to do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new AS
(select couvert_temp.id as id, ST_Difference(couvert_temp_sutton.geom,buff.geom) as geom
from couvert_temp_sutton, buff
where couvert_temp.id=buff.id);
```